# Deleted file still remains same in the media device i mounted

Tags: linux, mount, live-usb, media, parrotsec

Deleted file still remains same in the media device I mounted.
I am using Parrot Security OS live mode, where I have mounted a partition to delete a file. Now I am not able to delete it. Option is disabled, says readable file only. I have solved it by `mount -o remount` command and I can successfully delete it, but that comes back again as soon as I delete that file. Please help me with this problem.

Comment: Are you able to create files?

Comment: I don't know much about Parrot Security OS but can you give more information about the partition of the media? Is it an ntfs partitioned media? If it is like CentOS, you may need some extra packages like `ntfsprogs` to manipulate files in that media.